# How to make a trigger detect if a row is deleted or not?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have made the following trigger:

```
create or replace trigger TSM_ENTITY_TRG
before insert on TSM_ENTITY
for each row
begin
select TSM_ENTITY_ID_SEQ.nextval
into :new.ID
from dual;
end;
/
```

The sequence in the code is

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TSM_ENTITY_ID_SEQ
MINVALUE 12
START WITH 12
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

The trigger works as needed except for one thing, if I delete a row then the trigger keeps on adding increments to the rows. For example, the id of the row would be 12 then the next would be 13 then 14 then 15. Then let's say I deleted row 15 and added a new one afterwards. Then the rows id's would be listed as 12 then 13 then 14 then 16. Is there a way for the sequence or trigger to detect a gap and fill it?

Comment: This is normal behaviour of sequence. Sequence once used cannot be reused, check your functional scenario... how you want to handle.. take an eg. you added 13,14,15,16 and then deleted 14, what you expect your next inserted record to take the number 14 or 17 ??

Comment: "Is there a way to fix that?"   No, it's not fixable because it isn't broken.

Comment: @Twelfth edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Same answer.  There is no need for "gap free" values (it's quite counterproductive...read up on clustered index's, it's more important to have the next one in sequence than it is to have a continuous sequence).  If you have some wonky requirement to create a continuous sequence (wonky = not required and adds zero benefit)) , see zaratustra below.

Comment: If you care only about gaps that are result of delete, you might probably overcome the problem (for instance, by "after delete" trigger that stores deleted id in some new table (access to it must be serialized as Justin Cave pointed out), then in "before insert" you first check this table ). However, it doesn't solve the problem in general. Gaps may appear as result of sequence cache + shutdown, inserts +rollback. Then checking for gaps become extremely expensive.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Columns populated by sequences will have gaps.  If your requirement is to have gap-free values, you cannot use sequences.

If you really, really think that you need a gap-free set of values, then you would have to introduce a serialization mechanism that ensures that only one user at a time is inserting data into the table.  That is possible.  But it radically decreases the scalability and performance of your application.  And it radically increases the probability that you are going to have maintenance issues like sessions that have died while holding a lock that the DBA has to find and kill before anyone can continue working.  I've never come across a situation where business users, after hearing about the downsides of generating gap-free values, decided that they really wanted to incur those costs.

If you just want to see a gap-free set of values in a query, you can use analytic functions like `rank`

```
SELECT rank() over (order by id) gap_free_rank
  FROM tsm_entity;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **a way bad idea**, you have to ignore the values of your primary key. This values you need only to detect the row that the value points at.

As a solution of your task:

Let's assume we have this structure of the table:

```
create table TSM_ENTITY (
  id NUMBER(10),
  code VARCHAR2(20 char),
  name VARCHAR2(20 char)  
);
```

Then you can create a view based on the table:

```
CREATE VIEW TSM_ENTITY_V AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) AS id, t.code, t.name
  FROM TSM_ENTITY t
```

The ROW_NUMBER() function gives you a continuous range of numbers.